# Tichonoff theorem, closed subset of $\prod_{t \in T} X_t$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I'm studying a proof of Tichonoff Theorem:

$\prod_{t \in T} X_t$ is compact $\iff$ $\forall t\in T \ \ \ X_t$ is compact.

I have some problems understanding the short part : $\Rightarrow$.

I am familiar with the lemma stating that $X(y,s) \ni x \rightarrow x_s \in X_s $ is a homeomorphism.

$X(y,s) = \{x \in \prod_{t \in T} X_t \ \ | \ \ \pi_t(x)=\pi_t(y)  \ \ \ \forall t \neq s\}$

The proof of Tichonoff Theorem refers to the fact that $X(y,s)$ is a closed subset of $\prod_{t \in T} X_t$.

I suppose it somehow follows from Tichonoff's topology but I don't know how to prove that.

Could you help me?

Comment: Why not just use the fact that the projection map is continuous, so that it takes compact sets to compact sets?

Comment: $X(y,s) = \cap_{t\neq s} \pi_t^{-1}(\{\pi_t(y)\})$

Comment: @DBF: Right, indeed. I can just say that projection is continuous (from product topology) and surjective and that means that each $X_t = \pi_t(\prod X_t)$ is compact. There is no need to mention $X(y,s)$?

Comment: Yes; actually, the product topology is the initial topology for the projections, i.e., the smallest topology that makes projections continuous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product topology is the initial topology for projection maps : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology ; meaning the product topology is the smallest topology that makes the projections continuous. Since the projections are continuous, they send compact to compact, so that each space $X_t$ is compact.

Comment: Glad to help, Bilbo.

Comment: I was never a fan of the term "initial topology", in particular in this context.

Comment: I think it sort-of makes sense, since we have a topology on the "initial set" of a mapping.

Answer (score 3):

$X(y,s)$ need not be closed in $X$. Suppose that $T=\{0,1\}$, and $X_0$ and $X_1$ are copies of the [Sierpiński space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space). Let $y=\langle 1,1\rangle$ and $s=0$; then $X(y,0)=\{\langle 0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1\rangle\}=X_0\times\{1\}$, which is not closed in $X_0\times X_1$. (In fact it’s dense in $X_0\times X_1$).